# Jquery validation rules from loop?

Tags: jquery, validation

I have this dynamic textbox and I want to put it into validation rules.

I want to make the rules based on how many clothes there is dynamically from database using a `while` loop.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#sales').validate({
    rules: {
      'clothe[1]': {
        required: true
      }
      'clothe[2]': {
        required: true
      }
    }
  });
```

```html
<form id="sales">
  <td><input type="text" name="clothe[1]" id="clothe[1]"></td>
  <td><input type="text" name="clothe[2]" id="clothe[2]"></td>
</form>
```

Comment: welcome to StackOverflow! please, have a look at some info, like [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and update your question so it aligns better with the expected code of conduct.

Comment: You don't need a loop, or even JS code. As you're using the jQuery validate library, just put the validation rules directly in to the HTML.